# From Python serial to Arduino serial

Tags: python, c

I am working on kinda wierd thing which should communicate through serial protocol for controlling 2  servos , I need to adjust their angle and switch to which one it should go, so I have made simple protocol which is: 150p ( 150° to p servo ), I am trying to do it through a bytearray, but I actually cant format it properly, it still give me an error and some similiar thing to this, there is still problem with writing and I cant get the right format. Thanks for any help 
**TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)**

serp- servo p angle - def 90
sert- servo t angle - def 90

```
if x1>x_pos:
    serp = serp*1 - 5
    ser.open()
    ser.write(bytearray(serp),'\x70') """this should write 85p to the serial""" 
elif x1<x_pos:
    serp = serp*1 + 5
    ser.open()
    ser.write(bytearray(serp),'\x70') """ 95p """
if y1>y_pos:
    sert = sert*1 - 5
    ser.open()
    ser.write(bytearray(sert),'\x74') """ 85t"""
elif y1<y_pos:
    sert = sert*1 + 5
    ser.open()
    ser.write(bytearray(sert),'\x74') """ 95t """
x1=x_pos
y1=y_pos
ser.close()
```

My C code here :

```
void loop()
```

{

if ( Serial.available()> 0)

```
{
switch (GetChar ())
{
  case Ping:
    Serial.write ("Connection estabilished.\n");
    continue;

  case PANAngle:
  {
    int h=0;
    h = GetChar ();
    if(h >= '0' && h <= '9')              // is h a number?  
    pos = pos * 10 + h - '0';              // yes, accumulate the value

    else if(h == 'p')  // pan
    {
      panServo.write(pos);          
      Serial.print("Pan Servo angle: "); 
      Serial.println(pos); 
    }
  }
 case TILTAngle:
  {
  int j=0;  
  j = GetChar ();
  if(j >= '0' && j <= '9')              // is j a number?  
  pos = pos * 10 + j - '0';           // yes, accumulate the value
  else if(j == 't')  // tilt
    {
      tiltServo.write(pos);          
      Serial.print("Tilt Servo angle: "); 
      Serial.println(pos); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, let me reassure you that this is not a weird thing, but a rather common scheme (I mean the requirement, not the implementation). Second... Which part is giving you the error? The Python one? So the comments in Python that are given by `"""` are multiline and should be "closed" in the same way By the way, you can easily see the issue looking at the syntax highlighting even here on SO.

Comment: Thank you, edited , sorry, that is not a problem , python one is giving me an error in ser.write thing